# Method does not exist or incorrect signature: (List<Object__c>, Map<Id,Object__c>)

Tags: apex, trigger

I am trying to query all modified records from one custom Object and sending one email with all modified records. Where i getting error with trigger handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have written `onAfterUpdate_updatedAnswers(Map<Id, Question_Answer__c>    lNewQAs, Map<Id, Question_Answer__c> mOldQAs)`to take two maps, and you're calling it with a list and a map: `CSQuestionAnswerTriggerActions.onAfterUpdate_updatedAnswers(lNewQAs, mOldQAs);`

A quick fix is to change that second line it be:

```
CSQuestionAnswerTriggerActions.onAfterUpdate_updatedAnswers(new Map<Id, Question_Answer__c>(lNewQAs), mOldQAs);
```

Comment: Hi, @Aidan Why this code is not executing, i am not receiving email.